# How to modify Toolbar Icon to show Text in FCKEditor

Tags: fckeditor

**Does anyone know how I can add text into the toolbar?** I would like to add some text to one of the buttons just like how the button for "Source" has the small icon, but also has the word "Source" beside it to describe what that button does.

Basically none of my test users knows that the little mountain icon is used insert an image. Because of this, I would like to either replace that icon with the words "upload image" or I'd like to keep that little mountain icon, and have the words "upload image" beside it, to help people understand that's the icon for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea, never thought about it.

I believe you need to add a parameter to FCKToolbarButton. Here's a code that creates that Source button and its neighbor:

```
    case 'Source'           : oItem = new FCKToolbarButton( 'Source'    , FCKLang.Source, null, FCK_TOOLBARITEM_ICONTEXT, true, true, 1 ) ; break ;
    case 'DocProps'         : oItem = new FCKToolbarButton( 'DocProps'  , FCKLang.DocProps, null, null, null, null, 2 ) ; break ;
```

The difference in the constant (which equals 2, BTW) in the 4th parameter.